# VBA/Macro problem creating a table of correct height/width and creating that table without the last row of the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-office

I have written (with much help from StackOverflow, THANKS!) a macro that

- grabs excel files (7 in actuality only 2 presented in this example)
- migrates their worksheets into a master file (only one worksheet in each source excel file)
- removes viewing panes
- changes column widths

I'm having trouble with "Find the bottom right of the range, move up one row and select back to "home" and make a table name".

The high-level idea is I don't want the summary line at the bottom of each file.

I'm not certain that I've chosen the "best" solution for this section (i'd actually prefer to:

- find the bottom row
- delete it
- goto the "new" `xlLastCell`
- create the table from the range `a1:xlLastCell`

Additionally, the table created is "always" 8 rows tall x 19 columns (column S) wide.

I'm asking for help with two related items:

- Create my table without the bottom row
- create the table based on the variable nature of the dataset (I believe the solution to this MAY be setting a variable as each file is processed.

```
'Find the bottom right of the range, move up one row and select back to "home" and make a table name
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)). _
Resize(Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Columns.Count, _
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Rows.Count - 1).Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).Name = "xARPatient"
```

```
Sub aaaa()
Dim wb_source As Workbook
Dim wb_target As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb_target = Workbooks.Open("c:\Test\MEBIllingOffice.xlsm")
'assuming the sheet name is "xAccountARAgingPatient.xlsx" note - sheet names must be unique within target


'Import File #1''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'import file as a worksheet from other worbooks in the same directory
    Set wb_source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\xAccountARAgingPatient.xlsx")
      For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each LO In ws.ListObjects
          LO.Unlist
        Next
      Next
wb_source.Sheets("xAccountARAgingPatient.xlsx").Copy after:=wb_target.Sheets(wb_target.Sheets.Count)
'remove extraneous formatting
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Selection.ClearFormats
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
'Find the bottom right of the range, move up one row and select back to "home" and make a table name
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)). _
Resize(Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Columns.Count, _
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Rows.Count - 1).Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).Name = "xARPatient"
wb_source.Close

'Import File #2''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'import file as a worksheet from other worbooks in the same directory
    Set wb_source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\xAccountARAgingPayer.xlsx")
      For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each LO In ws.ListObjects
          LO.Unlist
        Next
      Next
wb_source.Sheets("xAccountARAgingPayer.xlsx").Copy after:=wb_target.Sheets(wb_target.Sheets.Count)
'remove extraneous formatting
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Selection.ClearFormats
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
'Find the bottom right of the range, move up one row and select back to "home" and make a table name
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)). _
Resize(Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Columns.Count, _
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Rows.Count - 1).Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).Name = "xARPayer"
wb_source.Close
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'wb_target.Save
'wb_target.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Dim rng As range, ws as worksheet

set ws = Activesheet
set rng = ws.Range("a1").currentregion  'select whole table
set rng = rng.resize(rng.rows.count - 1, rng.columns.count) 'make one row shorter...
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "xARPayer"
```